# Searching For String Literals

Tags: .net, string, localization, string-literals

In the quest for localization I need to find all the string literals littered amongst our source code. I was looking for a way to script this into a post-modification source repository check. (I.E. after some one checks something in have a box setup to check this stat) I'll probably use NAnt and CruiseControl or something to handle the management of the CVS (Well StarTeam in my case :( ) But do you know of any scriptable (or command line) utility to accurately cycle through source code looking for string literals? I realize I could do simple string look up based on regular expressions but want a little more bang for my buck. (Maybe analyze the string or put it into categories) Because a lot of times the string may not necessarily require translation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 and earlier:

1. Find In Files (CTRL+SHIFT+F)
2. Use: Regular Expressions
3. Find: **`:q`**  (quoted string)
4. Find All

Find Results window will now contain a report of all files, with line numbers and the line itself with the quoted string.

For Visual Studio 2012 and later search for `((\".+?\")|('.+?'))` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), hat-tip to [@CincauHangus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484578/cincauhangus))

Comment: For newer Visual Studio you should use:
((\".+?\")|('.+?')) reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For a narrower result use: (?<!(<.*|Resource.*|^.*\[.*))(\".+?\")  This will eliminate resource files and decorations

Comment: Jeff's (?<!(<.*|Resource.*|^.*[.*))(\".+?\") didn't work for me.  Seemed to make for a hung search.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the compiled binary instead of source, but Sysinternals' [Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) app might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find In Files (CTRL+SHIFT+F)
2. Find options -> Check `Use Regular Expressions`

For specific text within the literal:

3. Find what: `"+.*(MYSPECIFICTEXT)+.*"+`

For all literals

3. Find what: `"+.*"+`

Then

4. Find All

Answer (score 1):

To find all `Text="textonly"` instances use the following Regular Expression when searching:

```
(Text=)(")([a-z])
```

This is help for finding `Text="*"` but excluding text that's already been converted to use resource files:

```
Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, KeyNameFromResourceFile%>"
```

Also `(>)([a-z])` can be used to find literals between tags like so:

```
<h1>HeaderText</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer. To exclude commented out lines and summary lines, use this : ^(?!\s{0,}[/]{2,}).+((".+?")|('.+?'))

Comment: What do you mean by "complementing"? Which answer do you refer to? How is your post an answer according to [answer]? How does  work what you propose? What effect does it have? Why does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [C# parser on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/csparser) that you can probably use.

Answer (score 0):

hi this is regex for searching literals, that I use to find a text for translation.
it also includes empty spaces and different quotes

regex:

```
([",`,'])([\w,\s]*)([",`,'])
```

searchstring: var test='This is a test';