# Extract all the strings harded in the code

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I've a asp.net mv5 application I need to localize quickly. I've extracted all the string I've found in controllers/cshtml but I wish to know if there's something I can use to extract all the strings from a project... Even if it extracts no-sense string ( for e example "a" it would be fine, so I just have the evidence of that). I've tried resharper and ndepend but they won't suggest everything

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could probably search using a regular expression. Which I believe the IDE supports

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/164439/5233410